# (LocalDb)\MSSQLLocalDB as Server Name for Report Server Configuration Manager

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, database-administration

I'm doing the SSRS setup in my DEV environment.  I've been using (LocalDb)\MSSQLLocalDB for some of my databases. Now that I want to start using SSRS, can I use (LocalDb)\MSSQLLocalDB as a data source for SSRS?     I already tried, but I'm not able to connect it. However, if I use the server name (name of my computer) it works.

Do I have to use the actual server name?     Is local database (LocalDb)\MSSQLLocalDB a wrong way of doing it?   I'm assuming that the actual server name will be the best practice.

If I have to use the server name, that means that I will need to migrate my databases from (LocalDb)\MSSQLLocalDB to the instance of the server name.

What do you recommend?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

LocalDb instances run in your desktop session, and are meant for desktop applications (particularly Visual Studio).  So no.  You should migrate your databases to a service-based SQL Server instance for SSRS (which runs as a Windows Service) to access them.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. Yes, LocalDB works great on my applications.  I will migrate my DBs then. I guess that I want to run a SSRS report in one of my websites, I should point the code to the service-based SQL Server instance then. It's not that I should have both mixed. Right?

Comment: Right.  Once you have a need for a Service-based install, you mostly just use that.  You might still use LocalDb on your development computer, of course.

Comment: Great. Thanks so much for your help. Stay safe!